# Image Resource aren't rotated in Landscape with Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hi all 
this one surely is a simple one but I haven't made sense of is yet.

I'm working on an app in opengl es on android

everything goes well except when I load the textures.

I manage to open load and create all the textures without any problem, but the image displays itself rotated of 90.
it looks as if the application does not consider that its is in landscape when opening the image...

I solved the problem by turning all my textures of 90 degrees but I would sure like to figure this one out

because it is the only thing that is not rotated,
the top bar is rotated,
the touch coordinated are rotated,
the h and w of the surface are good,

here are some code snippets that I think are relevant

in the manifest
`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

on Create of the application

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

`InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(id);`

`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);`

`GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);`

Any ideas

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all 
sorry for the inconvenience, I actually figured out that I had inverted 2 lines in my uv map and it happened to look exactly as if all the textures were rotated.
sorry about that 
jason